# Creating a function to see if word inputted is in a list

Tags: python, function

Very new and green to python (we all start somewhere!), trying to figure out how to do this:

> Write a function that when called will check to see if the word input is contained on the following list `["dog, "pony", "cat", "tiger"]`.  The function should return a true or false.

```py
def my_list():
    print("Hello, what is the word I'm thinking of?")
list=["dog", "pony", "cat", "tiger"]
if my_list() in list:
     print("True")
else:
     print("False")
```

Comment: Actually did try and write it out myself...only so many error symbols one can take before they ask for help. And no, I am not in school, I am trying to learn coding and have been scouring the internet looking for sample problem sets to try.

Comment: This is what I originally had come up with...where was I going wrong?                        def my_list():
    print("Hello, what is the word Im thinking of?")
list=["dog", "pony", "history", "cat", "tiger"]
if my_list() in list:
     print("True")
else:
     print("False")

Comment: I don't see any code _in your question_ (where it belongs). If you can't come up with _anything_ at all, you need to be reading a Python tutorial or its documentation — stackoverflow isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the code representing your attempt in it.

Comment: done, if you could have a look that would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is homework?

```py
def homework(data):
    animal = ["dog", "pony", "cat", "tiger"]
    if data in animal:
        return True
    return False


you_input = input('input: ')
print(homework(you_input))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Actually did try and write it out myself...only so many error symbols one can take before they ask for help.  And no, I am not in school, I am trying to learn coding and have been scouring the internet looking for sample problem sets to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) operator to check if an element is in a sequence such as a `list`:

```
def check_list(word):
    return word in ["dog", "pony", "cat", "tiger"]

guess = input("Hello, what is the word I'm thinking of? ")
print(repr(guess), 'in list?', check_list(guess))
```